# Setting a new DNS for open-uri in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, open-uri

I'm having a problem to access a web site from RoR using open-uri.

In my local machine I have no problem but on the server the servers DNS doesn't resolve the uri.

Is there a way to set google DNSs before an open-uri call?

Thanks.

```
require 'open-uri'
open("fuel-prices-europe.info")
```

Comment: Does the website have a public-facing DNS address that can be accessed using a web browser? For using google (or some ISP) DNS, can you set your app to use your system or profile DNS servers?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the resolve in /etc/hosts?  or just use the ip?